# Can I render an inline formset without data in an update view?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, inline-formset

I have this models:

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    show_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class PicturePrice(models.Model):
    picture = models.ForeignKey(Picture)
    price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

With these models, I'm trying to know each time that a picture has a new price, and the date that each price has been added. Something like this:

```
Pictures: 1, 2, 3

Picture 1:
Price 5$ 3/16/2016
Price 3$ 3/18/2016

Picture 2:
Price 3$ 3/16/2016

Picture 3:
Price 5$ 3/16/2016
Price 3$ 3/17/2016
Price 4$ 3/18/2016
```

Like this, I know what is the updated price and what has been the last prices.

I have this inline formset for the price:

```
price_formset=inlineformset_factory(
    Picture,
    PicturePrice,
    extra=0,
    min_num=1,
    can_delete=True,
    widgets={
    'price' : forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class':'form-control price_per_pic',
        'maxlength' : 5
    })}
)
```

This works well when I call it in the view,but when I try to add a new price, it shows a textbox with the previous price, to edit it. I don't want to edit the price, I just want to add a new register to the database.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `extra` value in your `price-formset` to be greater than 0 (the number of empty forms you'd like). So, if you'd like 1 empty form:

```
price_formset_inlineformset_factory(
    ...
    extra=1,
    ...
)
```